# Implement JS back-end and provide it an existing React front-end as an `/api` URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've got an React app, which calls internally: `/api/*` actions. In my case these actions are satisfied by `NginX` which loads relevant back-end code and returns JSON response.

I would like this React app to be "self-served", I would like to implement API back-end: `/api/*` using JS, so the code runs in the browser.

My app uses: `react-router`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={"/users/:path*"} component={UsersPage} />
        <Route path={"/api/:action*"} component={ApiComponent} /> // Return RAW Json here, is it possible?
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Is it possible somehow to resolve the `/api/*`, so I can implement it in my `ApiComponent` and return raw JSON?

I've also experimented with Express JS:

```
app.group("/api", (router) => {

    router.get("/action", (req, res) => {
        // Implement API action here
    });

});

app.use('/public', express.static('public')) // This allows assets to be loaded from filesystem

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile('./index.html'); // This loads React app
});
```

which worked very well, but now I've ended up with a problem, how to run this Express JS / NodeJS, in a browser context.

In other words, my question is what are the ways to implement API on the front-end, provide to to existing React app, and run it all in browser.

Comment: what is your API doing or returning?

Comment: It connects to another API, does some transformation and returns JSON in a front-end compatible format.

Comment: then you can call that API in frontend and do transformation there only, maybe create a function for that. what is the challenge?

Comment: There is an app, which requires an API method in its origin e.g.: `/get/user`. This `/get/user` is an HTTP request which can be served by e.g. NginX/Apache or whatever server, which serves the app to the browser.
Now imagine, that you don't want to run NginX/Apache and self serve the response to the app from the browser. You can implement API in JS, but how do you actually intercept the `/get/user` request and provide the response?
The only way so far is to modify one of the app methods, so instead of calling: `/get/user` it can implement the API...

Comment: ... but modifying the app, means that you need to have the source code, you need to have license allowing you to do so, and so on.
My question purely touches the aspect of self-serving the request that originates from the app you don't have much control on. It's basically implementing the missing HTTP interface, but using JS and also running in the browser.

Comment: Then, you can use register a service worker which essentially act as proxy server and can intercept all http requests. If using lib. like axios, it has intercept functionality. Or you might want to use browser extension like this https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome.

Comment: Thanks @AnujSharma the interceptors are something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an HTTP client library like Axios, you can use an interceptor, which is a function that gets called for every single HTTP request made and the response received by your application in the browser itself.

[image: axios interceptor]

Here is the sample code,

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (request) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    request.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer <token>';
    return request;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    if (response.status === 401) {
        window.location = '/login';
    }    
    return response;
  }, function (error) {    
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Another way is to register a service worker, which essentially acts as a proxy server and can intercept all HTTP requests.

Also, you can use browser extension like https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome which creates a Web Server for Chrome, serves web pages from a local folder over the network, using HTTP. Runs offline.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for React elements to return raw JSON because all React elements return a special object.

Maybe, you should just set a proxy in your webpack/vite config to point all `/api` requests to your node server.

Comment: Where is the node server supposed to be running? It's all meant to run in user browser, so user can exactly see what code is being executed.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue, nodejs code cannot run in browser. It's a server implementation of js.

Comment: ... so how your proxy is supposed to help given that I already have Express JS proxy?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue, it will point all request from `reactaddress/api` to `expressadress/api`

Comment: Right I see, well I am looking for a way to intercept the request and self-serve it. Perhaps it's not possible to achieve it with today's technology. Maybe ServiceWorkers / Web containers could be used.
In other words, when React calls an API: `/api/getMeUsers`, I would like it to reach to the application itself, execute some JS and return JSON.